# How do I fetch and load React routes from an API?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I currently have a sidebar with 6 hardcoded routes. Some have hardcoded sub routes; when I click a route, it expands to show its sub routes. One of the routes gets its sub routes from an API (returns JSON), how do I load those into the sidebar's sub menu? Lazy loading preferably:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Click E, and it fetches the routes from the API and displays them:

```
A
B
C
D
E
  1
  2
  3
F
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `<router>` is called from `render()` method in a React Class, why not putting the available routes in a state? Then, if an API update the state (`this.setState()`) with availables routes, `<router>` will be re-render.

Comment: My router is like so:
    `ReactDOM.render(
      <Router history={appHistory}>
      ..
      </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root'));`

Comment: I've since discovered the wonders of Redux and React Router 4. However this works with RR3 so I'll mark it as the solution. Thanks.